# SimpleModal Makes Div in Modal Dialog Opacity: 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css, simplemodal

Before I ask the question I realize I may not be using the full potential of simplemodal, so bear with me please.

I have the following modal dialog in my HTML:

```
<div id="confirm_delete_role">
   <h1>Are You Sure You Want To Proceed?</h1>
   <div id="confirm_parameter_role"></div>
   <p class="right_button"><a class="ui_navigation" href="javascript:$.modal.close(); var e = document.getElementById('confirm_parameter'); e.innerHtml = ''; var f = hLoader.setCheckStatus('confirm/callback'); f();">Proceed</a>
   <a class="ui_navigation" href="javascript:$.modal.close(); var e = document.getElementById('confirm_parameter'); e.innerHtml = '';">Cancel</a></p>
</div>
```

In another area of javascript where I summon this dialog I load up the confirm_parameter_role beforehand and provide a callback:

```
hLoader.loadDiv('admin/roles/confirm', 'return-parameter', undefined, 'confirm_parameter_role', function(){
               hLoader.setCheckStatus('confirm/callback', function(){
                   var replace = document.getElementById('input_parameter_role');
                   replace = replace.options[replace.selectedIndex].value;
                   hLoader.loadViewportContent('admin/roles/delete/role/' + document.getElementById(idSrc).value + '/replace/' + replace);
               });

               $(' #confirm_delete_role ').modal();
            });
```

hLoader.loadDiv is a slightly modified wrapper around the jQuery .load function, but essentially performs the same thing (It loads the address admin/roles/confirm, reads #return-parameter and puts it into #confirm_parameter_role).  It creates this:

```
<div id="confirm_parameter_role">
<form>
        <label for="input_parameter_role" id="input_parameter_role-label">Replacement Role For Current Accounts:</label>
        <select name="input_parameter_role" id="input_parameter_role">
            <option value="1" label="Clients">Clients</option>
            <option value="2" label="Employees">Employees</option>
            ETC.
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

The whole process works great except for one thing.  Mysteriously, my #confirm_parameter_role div has it's style set to "Opacity: 0;" at some point (not by my code) so when the modal dialog box appears... there's no form or select bar.

Any ideas?  Anybody else getting their div's inside their modal boxes set to 0 opacity?  Thanks ahead for any clues.

Comment: Have you used Firebug to dig around and see what style script sets the opacity?  If it's a per-element style, I believe Firebug can set a breakpoint on an attribute change.

Comment: I did what you suggested.  It seems there's an incompatibility with how SimpleModal clones and replaces the div and the fadeIn and fadeOut functions I was using with the jQuery .load function.  When I set the persist option on the modal it helped, and when I didn't use fade functions it worked as well.  Any clues on the incompatibility would be helpful otherwise... I worked around it.  Thanks for the Firebug suggestion, that cleared it up for me.

Comment: How and when are you calling the fadeIn and fadeOut functions? Is it in the .load callback or in the loadDiv function?

Comment: It is in the .load callback that is employed in the loadDiv function.

Comment: It makes sense that fadeIn and fadeOut would set the div's opacity.  I don't know jQuery very well, but there must be a way to combine write a custom filter, which happens after fadeIn/fadeOut and would remove the opactity style.

Comment: SimpleModal only sets the opacity of the overlay...so it sounds like you have some other issue here.